# 'tuple' object is not callable in pool.apply multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, oop, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I am implementing the class oneShot_learner which takes one instance from one dataset and pairs it up with all the instances from another dataset. The process is repeated along the indexes of the former dataset and thus I have thought of running it in parallel to speed up the computation. Nonetheless, the process ends up in an error.

```
class oneShot_learner(object):

    def __init__ (self, model, supportSet, querySet):
        self.model = model
        self.supportSet = supportSet
        self.querySet = querySet

    def __call__(self, N, k):
        return oneShot_learner.test_multipleShot(self,N, k) 

    def test_multipleShot(self, N, k):
        indexes = self.querySet.index

        num_workers = mp.cpu_count()  
        pool = mp.Pool(num_workers)

        predicted_class = []
        predicted_probability = []

        for index in indexes: 
            [predicted_label, predicted_proba] = pool.apply(oneShot_learner.test_oneShot(self, N, k, index))
            pool.close()
            print(predicted_label)         
            predicted_label, predicted_proba = oneShot_learner.test_oneShot(self, N, k, index)

        predicted_class.append(predicted_label)
        predicted_probability.append(predicted_proba)

        return predicted_class, predicted_probability

    def test_oneShot(self, N, k, index):

        # Counters
        prediction = []
        prediction_proba = []

        # Evaluation mode
        self.model.eval()

        with torch.no_grad():
            for i in range(k):

                N_way_oneShot, random_label, train_label = oneShot_learner.make_oneShot_task(self,N,index) # This function only creates the relevant DataFrame (not in this post for concision purposes)

                inputs1, inputs2, labels = torch.tensor(N_way_oneShot.iloc[:,:2048].values), torch.tensor(N_way_oneShot.iloc[:,2049:-1].values), torch.tensor(N_way_oneShot.iloc[:,-1].values)
                if (on_gpu):
                    inputs1, inputs2, labels = inputs1.cuda(), inputs2.cuda(), labels.cuda()
                    self.model = self.model.cuda()

                    probs = self.model(inputs1, inputs2, labels, predict = False)

                    max_similarity, index_similarity = torch.max(probs,0)
                    val_label = train_label[index_similarity.item()]

                    prediction.append(val_label)   
                    prediction_proba.append(max_similarity.item())

            predicted_label = max(set(prediction), key = prediction.count)
            predicted_proba = np.mean(prediction_proba)
            #set_trace()
        return predicted_label, predicted_proba
```

I can see that the actual tuple is output with both predicted_label and predicted_proba by test_oneShot when I set_trace() at the test_oneShot function (e.g. I get --Return-- (0, 0.7136549353599548)). However, I cannot retrieve the tuple thereafter in the test_multipleShot output.

```
learner = oneShot_learner(model, train, val)
prediction, prediction_proba = learner(1,3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-31506cfb542e> in <module>
      1 learner = oneShot_learner(drugmodel, fp_train, fp_val)
----> 2 prediction, prediction_proba = learner(1,3)

<ipython-input-107-044dd2a29c0b> in __call__(self, N, k)
      7 
      8     def __call__(self, N, k):
----> 9         return oneShot_learner.test_multipleShot(self,N, k)
     10 
     11     def test_multipleShot(self, N, k):

<ipython-input-107-044dd2a29c0b> in test_multipleShot(self, N, k)
     19 
     20         for index in indexes:
---> 21             [predicted_label, predicted_proba] = pool.apply(oneShot_learner.test_oneShot(self, N, k, index))
     22             pool.close()
     23             print(predicted_label)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in apply(self, func, args, kwds)
    259         Pool must be running.
    260         '''
--> 261         return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
    262 
    263     def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: You are passing `oneShot_learner.test_oneShot(self, N, k, index)` to `Pool.apply`, which returns a `tuple` object but `tuple` objects are not callable. You probably mean to pass `oneShot_learner.test_oneShot` itself to `.apply`.

Comment: Also, for the sake of all decency, please pick either camel case or snake case (you should use the latter in Python), not a weird hybridization of both like `test_oneShot`

Comment: you mean Pool.apply(oneShot_learner.test_oneShot)? How do I pass the arguments then? Thanks, I will pick snake case

Comment: Have you read the [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply)?

Comment: Note, for *class names*, it should be CapitalCase,

Comment: I have read the documentation before and tried pool.apply(oneShot_learner.test_oneShot, args = (self, N, k, index), but yields the error Can't pickle local object 'DrugModel.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'. So I also tried pathos multiprocessing without success, too.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue. But taking a step back, it looks like you are trying to run multiple processes, where each task involve using some PyTorch-based GPU/CUDA processing. This is almost certainly not a good idea, at least, if you are expecting to *improve* performance.